# My ex boyfriend took over my Facebook account

Tags: facebook

He knew my email address and password. He logged in and changed everything. I know his email address, however if I try to "I forgot my password" it will only send it to his phone or alternate email address. He's posting inappropriate things and has added his name along with mine on my page. It looks like a joint account.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The answer is simple - change your email and facebook password, and NEVER tell your password to anyone. Never.